# azure devops - my jobs are Queued for a very long time

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

Today i'm setting up azure devops to checkout how it can help us in our build/release process. It is a slow process I have to say especially because al my jobs are queued and I don't know why. I have two pipelines which do basically the same thing. But one is made with the classic editor and one with YAML.

```
# Xamarin.Android
# Build a Xamarin.Android project.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute an app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/xamarin

trigger:
- master

schedules:
- cron: "0 3 * * Mon-Fri"
  displayName: M-F 3:00 AM (UTC) daily build
  branches:
    include:
    - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'macos-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  outputDirectory: '$(build.binariesDirectory)/$(buildConfiguration)'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'

- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(outputDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

The log of the job itself doesn't say very much:

```
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: macos-latest
Queued: Today at 15:13 [manage parallel jobs]

The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. Current position in queue: 3
Job preparation parameters
2 queue time variables used
system.debug : true
agent.diagnostic : true
```

I don't know what the problem is of the queued jobs.... The project itself is just the template when you create a new xamarin forms project. 
Also as a side note, if the build succeeds where does azure put the apk file? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure I want to duplicate answers, but here's a link to an answer that could resolve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72986712/10907864

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation, there is a recently event of availability degradation of Azure DevOps, which affected these services, and it has been resolved now. This could affect customers in 
Europe.  If you want to know more information, please click here: [Hosted Pools Availability Degradation in Europe](http://Hosted%20Pools%20Availability%20Degradation%20in%20Europe)

> Our engineers are currently investigating an event impacting Azure
>   DevOps hosted pools in Europe. The event is being triaged and we will
>   post an update as soon as we know more.
>
> The issue is now fully mitigated. Our engineers will be investigating
>   this further to learn from and reduce the risk of potential
>   recurrences. We apologize for the impact this had on our customers.

[image][image]

About the second part, agree with Krzysztof Madej . After the build succeeds, you need to publish the file as artifact for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I had this the same, so I assume that this is global issue. Maybe related to this:

> From March 24th - 26th, 2020 many customers in Europe and the United
>   Kingdom experienced delays in their builds and releases targeting our
>   hosted Windows and Linux agents. This incident was caused by VM
>   capacity constraints arising from the global health pandemic that led
>   to increased machine reimage times and then increased wait times for
>   available agents. Many customers experienced significant delays in
>   their pipelines over multiple days. We sincerely apologize for the
>   impact of this incident.

I know that this is related to March, but could appear again. Just a guess.

**Part 2**

Since you build your app you must publish your artifact (apk file). You can use [Publish Build Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops)

```yaml
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathToPublish: $(outputDirectory)
    artifactName: MyBuildOutputs
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this page stumped as to why I was getting no error message in the pipeline.

Turns out when I had changed the pipeline yaml file name, I had accidently set the pipeline status to 'Paused'