# 'Running other requests issue' when build definition execute using Microsoft hosted agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The error message that I receive is `Error: The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. Current position in queue: 1`

When I execute the build definition using Microsoft agent, it results in the error above. The build execution took days and it has been abounded. Can someone please help me to run out of this issue?

The scenario I tried with Microsoft agent "Azure pipelines":

1. Reinstalling the self-hosted agent and reconfigure the agent again.

Comment: Not sure I want to duplicate answers, but here's a link to a StackOverflow answer that could resolve this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72986712/10907864

Answer (score 6):

Please follow below steps to check the status of your self-hosted agents.

Navigate to azure devops Project settings-->Agent pools-->Select the agent pool where your self-hosted agent resides-->Go to Agents tab-->make sure the agent is online

[image]

If the agent is offline. Please go to the self-hosted agent installation folder and manually start the agent by runing `run.cmd` file. If the agent cannot be started. Please reinstall your self-hosted agent.

If the agent is already online. That means there are not enough agents in the agent pool to run your pipelines. You need to create more self-hosted agents.

Note:

If you are using classic UI pipeline. You should know you can configure the agent selection in two places ie. **Pipeline** scope and **Agent job** scope

[image]

The agent configuration in Agent job scope will override the agent configuration in Pipeline scope.

If you want to use Microsoft agents. Please make sure you select the Microsoft agents in the Agent job scope.

[image]

Comment: None of those and also everything worked fine two days ago.

Comment: I missed running run.cmd