# The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are running a pipeline that has run successfully for ages. It is failing as of yesterday. We are getting the error

> The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests.
> The `agent pool` is offline

[image]

This [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66008030/running-other-requests-issue-when-build-definition-execute-using-microsoft-hos) says I need to run.cmd, but I am not running a self-hosting agent.

We also get this additional error

> Failed to get scaleset from Azure with error: No service Endpoint found with Id: xxxx and Scope xxxx

How do I bring the agent back online and is that the solution to fix the error that is preventing the publish/deploy. If not, how do we fix this issue.

Comment: In the Settings tab, can you see what's the scale set name and check if the scale set still exists in your Azure subscription?

Comment: @CharlesHan Yes it does exist and we restarted it. Thank you.

Comment: Did this fix your issue? If yes, @CharlesHan should submit this as an answer so the issue has an accepted answer than.

Comment: @promicro No, We had already tried restarting and it exists but that did not fix the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three kinds of icon of agent pool in Azure DevOps.

Microsoft-hosted agent:

[image]

Self-hosted agent:

[image]

VMSS(Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set):

[image]

So the type you are using is VMSS(Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set) pool. This type of agent pool will based on service connection of one of your project or subscription.

So if the machines are in the VMSS, you can try to edit your VMSS pool settings on Azure DevOps side, you can set up another service connection(please make sure the related register app on azure portal side has required permissions to the VMSS).

If no machine instances or the previous instances were been deleted, then the object on DevOps side will not be able to recovery. You can rec-config to a new VMSS or delete the old pool and create a new one.

Comment: Deleting the old pool and recreating the new one had the desired effect of updating the new instances in the scale set to the latest too. And when they appeared (the instances in the VMSS) in DevOps agent pool again after being recreated they were online. Excellent suggestion. Thank you @Bowman Zhu-MSFT